# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute') ¿alguien me puede apoyar con este problema?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Estaba intentando hacer un command handler para un bot de discord, no mentire que use el de un tutorial en el cual usan el "execute" y funciona perfectamente.

cuando ejecuto un comando la consola arroja

[image: Este error]

y muere ¿alguien me puede ayudar porfavor?

[Este es el video del cual saque el codigo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrEWMHVt8Bc)

Este es el index:

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const intents = new discord.Intents();
const client = new discord.Client({ intents: 32767 });

const fs = require('fs');
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');

client.commands = new discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./comandos').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./comandos/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    const [command, ...args] = message.content.split(/ +/g);
    let cmd = client.commands.find((c) => c.name === command || c.alias && c.alias.includes(command));
    if(!cmd){
        cmd.execute(client, message, args);
    } else {
        if(!cmd) {
            return;
        }
    }
});

const config = require('./config.json');
const prefix = config.prefix;

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`He iniciado sesion como ${client.user.tag} | By: MillionDreamer`);
    client.user.setActivity(`${prefix}help | By: MillionDreamer`, { type: 'PLAYING' });
});

client.login(config.token);
```

y este es el cuerpo que uso para los comandos:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")


module.exports = {
    name: "",
    alias: [""],

    execute(client, message, args) {



    }
}
```

Comment: estas en windows?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!